# Why are multiple answers allowed on C SE?

Tags: discussion

Peter Turner wants it asked. So here's the question. Why are multiple answers allowed on SE?

Answer (score 6):

**Why are multiple answers allowed on Christianity SE?**

Well, the truth be known, you asked the question to Peter Turner in a comment and he told you to go to Meta with the question.

This question belongs here rather than in the comments of a question on the main site!

All Stack Exchange sites start off in [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) and if they are successful enough, they go on to Beta and eventually graduate into it’s own site.

As an example I will choose [Proof Assistants](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants) which is in it’s Beta level at the moment. It’s main Area 51 page states that questions with **”2.5 answers per question is good, only 1 answer per question needs some work. On a healthy site, questions receive multiple answers and the best answer is voted to the top.”** This is Stack Exchange hopeful  policy!

Thus multiple answers are a sign of a healthy Stack Exchange Sites of which Christianity SE belongs to!

Nevertheless parameters must be placed in questions to avoid opinion based answers which are a dime a dozen. That is why we do not allow questions that can be answered from multiple denominations, unless asking for an overview or a comparative question. In this sense the Trinitarian tag is commonly abused. And should be restrained to a particular denomination to avoid the theological opinions of various Christian denominations and communities. The system will flag questions with too many answers, thus potentially indicating a lack of scoping in the post itself.

Do not forget: [Real Questions Have Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/) Stack Exchange’s six guidelines for questions.

> **Constructive subjective questions:**
>
> 1. inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”.
> 2. tend to have long, not short, answers.
> 3. have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone.
> 4. invite sharing experiences over opinions.
> 5. insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references.
> 6. are more than just mindless social fun.
>
> **What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?**
>
> 1. every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite __?”
> 2. your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use __ for __, what do you use?”
> 3. there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> 4. we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if __ happened?”
> 5. it is a rant disguised as a question: “__ sucks, am I right?”

One should definitely insist that theological opinions and interpretations be backed up with facts and references.

Comment: "should be restrained to a particular denomination to avoid the opinions of various Christian denominations and communities" This causes people to just add an arbitrary scope to get it within the rules, and biases the scoping toward Catholicism, because it is the largest denomination.

Comment: The problem is that there are lots of questions people want answers to about, say, Trinitarians, or Protestants. If you guys enforce this, I think I'll just pick a random Trinitarian non-creedal proxy denomination, and ask through that, so I can get similar sorts of answers. Searchability takes a hit, of course, which is the whole point of C SE.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather There's a natural scoping for each subject matter. Questions about the Trinity itself should be scoped to Trinitarianism (although we have historically allowed more specific scopings; personally I'd prefer we broaden such questions to the natural scoping.) That said, if you think there is an issue with how the site currently operates, threatening like you have in these comments to be a nuisance will not be conducive to having your concerns heard. I don't understand what your actual current concern is, all I see is a threat. Please don't be like that.

Comment: @curiousdannii AFAICT, these mods are threatening to try to shut down most of the questions I actually find interesting and use the site for, and that many others do as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons on Christianity.SE that a question gets multiple answers.

I'll start with the worst reasons

1. Answers from trolls.
2. Answers from people who just want to hate on the question
3. Comments on the question disguised as answers
4. Comments on other answers disguised as answers
5. Answers from people who want to post a contrary position to the question asked
6. Answers that don't quite understand the question
7. Answers that supplement an already given answer in an unsubstantial way.

   7a. Mike's answer was great, I just wanna say that...

   7b. (or in a overview), also the Anabaptist perspective is ...
8. Answers that are just a rant tangential to the question
9. Answers that are a rant about the question, advice opinion or personal experience
10. Answers that are wrong.

All of these are bad answers, with the exception of wrong answers, should be flagged.

The only answer that should exist on the site is an answer that stands alone and completely answers the question.

There's no reason to assume that two people are going to answer the same question from the same perspective in the same way.  Christianity has simply been around for too long to expect that. Therefore it is perfectly acceptable to post another answer, especially if you think you have a better, more detailed way of writing an answer. If you just have another point to add, it's OK to add it to an existing post as long as you don't change the meaning of the post.

Now, you may have noticed something missing.

Answers that offer a different, yet equally true perspective, on the question.  These are allowed of course.  But that means that the question is not scoped well enough.

Think about it this way.  If I can't answer a question from an unasked for viewpoint, how can another poster see your question and answer it from a different viewpoint?

Therefore, if I want to answer a question about the whether the Bible says such'n'such is cool (1) entirely consisting of conciliar documents and (2) another person considers these "so much straw" and only wants to use commentaries from the 16th century and (3) another person relies solely on the Summa Theologica.  Then we're at an impasse.

You have to choose, as an answerer, which is true.

HOWEVER, if you asked (a) "according to the Catholic Church does such 'n such Bible verse mean such and such is cool"  and (b) "according to a Reformed understanding of scripture does such 'n such a Bible verse mean such 'n such is cool" then you can have (1) and (3) answer question (a) because the answers of (a) accept the authority of (1) and (3),  they can help each other out ideally or post standalone answers, but they don't contradict each other's appeal to (legitimate) authority,

You also can have (b) answered by (1) and (3) because they (should) accept the council AND the commentaries (and the commentary author probably accepted the council whether the Protestant poster cares not).

If, however, you fail to scope your questions, then when a Catholic quotes Pope Eugene and a Protestant quotes Luther and a Swedenborgian quotes Maya Angelou, they have to fight over who is best and **this is exactly the sort of thing we are committed to avoid on this website**.

Comment: "The only answer that should exist on the site is an answer that stands alone **and completely answers the question**." Why? A great partial answer would be a useful contribution.

Comment: @one a person who wants to post a partial answer should just edit the original answer.  There is no harm in doing that.  The same principle on StackOverflow applies here. If someone posts an incomplete code snippet to supplement someone else's broken code, it is not a useful contribution.   My feeling is that the only appropriate time to post another answer is when you know a deeper truth.   A superficial answer ought to be supplanted by a deep answer;  A milky answer can be supplanted by a meaty answer.

Comment: "a person who wants to post a partial answer should just edit the original answer. There is no harm in doing that." What if the original answerer doesn't think the edit is correct, tho'?

Comment: Fixing code snippets seems to be in a different class (well, if it's not functional programming or something, that is :o) ). The correlate here would be more like fixing a typo here, IMO, or minor factual fixes, say.

Comment: @one that person can roll it back.  But truly, it's not entirely up to them whether to accept the edits.  Generally speaking though, a complete answer will not need more facts added to it.  One good corollary stackoverflow would be using different 3rd party modules to accomplish something.   Like, I can accomplish the same thing with pytest or the built in unittest in python, I approach the same question in the Dominican or Franciscan tradition in Catholicism; but if you tell me to program in Assembly instead, that's like giving me a Bible only answer and not telling me what processor it's for

Comment: Mind if I add some points to your list here? Isn't complete enough. Actually, I'm going to go back through all your answers and make sure they're 'complete'. <<< seems like opening a pandora's box of contention and difficulty on the site. I've had people 'correct' my answers, and generally they weren't 'corrections' but errors. Remember an answer is attributed to a specific someone on the page.

Comment: @one just read the help on edits, https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/editing you can add points if there relevant.

Comment: Peter, did you read the list of reasons given for editing a post at that link? It does not explicitly state something like "making major edits to add further points not intended by the original author" or something like that.

Comment: The emphasis instead is on minor edits - typos, clarifying the meaning without changing the meaning, ... *Maybe* the point about incorporating info in the comments applies, but I'm skeptical this usually works for C SE due to the lack of agreement in many cases that what's said in the comments is correct.

Comment: @one exactly, you shouldn't make major edits, but you can make minor edits - not changing the intention of the poster. Especially if you come to some sort of agreement in the comments. Otherwise when I come by with my big broom it will all be for naught.

Comment: It's like the doctrine of the clarity of scripture. Often, people disagree about what's clear wrt the Bible. So much for that principle ... Coding is a very different subject area, where different guidelines and goals should apply, and where, indeed, more answers are black and white (of course, even there there are interminable debates about approach, style, and so on).

Comment: Ya, but adding a substantial section of Miaphysites to answer might involve 'major edits'. Why not just put it in as a complementary answer?

Comment: @one all you'd be doing is illustrating that the question was not properly scoped, VTC the question instead.

Comment: "all you'd be doing is illustrating that the question was not properly scoped" Why does this follow? Rather, it shows that one answerer didn't include all relevant components of an answer.

Comment: That a question admits of complexity in answer **just doesn't mean** the question is 'improperly scoped'. I don't know *where* you're getting this. It sounds to me like you just want less commenting on the site, and think your approach will 'solve' that. This to me is implementing a policy for a completely wrong reason.

Comment: @one the point is to reduce ambiguity as much as humanly possible.  The fact that I don't like your questions has nothing to do with the fact that I don't think you should be able to ask about the Trinity, I don't like your questions because you speak ambiguously about the Trinity.  If you asked about a 2022 understanding of the doctrine as held by the Catholic Church, which is the scope of nearly all of our Catholicism questions then I'd be very happy with your participation.  But all you're doing is strawmanning "Trinitarians".

Comment: If a typical person goes to the internet with a similar question re Trinitarianism, do you really think most are going to be putting 'hypostatic unionists' into their search terms? No, they're going to ask about Trinitarians.

Comment: Asking questions about T is not 'straw-manning' T. It's asking a question. Got a good answer? Great, put it in. Think the relevant answer is complex? Great, say so.

Comment: Even with Biblical Unitarianism (a small segment of Reformed Christianity), answers are often complex, with some BUs saying x, some saying y, and so on. Could the person further reduce the scope to a part of contemporary BU? Sure. Should they? I don't see what the compelling reason is.

Comment: No, please stop pretending like you own the site or even remotely know what you're talking about, nobody agrees with you, some people just aren't as willing to ignore you, Curiousdannii is giving you an extreme benefit of the doubt.   But your ambivalence to the rules set out here, that the answers about the Trinity _need_ to be representative of Christendom at the time of the council of Nicaea and not based on hermeneutics or interpretation is going to do nothing but drive away users from the site.  Arguing in comments will have diminishing returns.

Comment: When you ask a question about the Trinity, you are asking the question about a common interpretation of the Council of Nicaea or you are not asking a question.  Do you agree with this statement?

Comment: I'm using a word, 'Trinitarian', that most people would use when formulating a similar question. Most people aren't even aware of the Council of Nicaea!

Comment: Many people are making claims about 'Trinitarians' or 'Trinitarianism'. They are raising questions about *that worldview*. That 'Trinitarianism' actually admits of complexity, and that how Trinitarian A may respond to the question is different from Trinitarian B, is interesting and important. But a questioner doesn't need to know all that to ask a question! The questioner doesn't need to, and probably usually shouldn't, be scoping his question to Trinitarians-A, then another for Trinitarians-B, then another f or Trinitarians-C, then another for Trinitarians-D, and so on, ...

Comment: ... shooting up 10 slightly differently phrased questions using technical terms to cover all the bases.

Comment: Hold on, is your argument that I should shoot up 20 iterations of a question about Trinitarianism?

Comment: Honestly, why stop there, since you want to be as unambiguous as possible. 50 variations? 100?

Comment: @one if stackexchange would let you, I'd say go for it.  We don't pay anybody for content.  The more questions we have, the closer we get to beating the Judaism site, which is in my 2023 PMP goals somewhere.  The worst thing you can do is ask a question that gets 8 or 10 good answers from different perspectives.

Comment: "The worst thing you can do is ask a question that gets 8 or 10 good answers" ??? I **just don't get it.** That would be fantastic. Alas, that is not usually the case.

Comment: @one If there are more than a few good answers (that don't overlap) then you have to do a "breadth first" search to find what you're looking for - (Ignatian spirituality vs an Anabaptist perspective), since there is an inherent ordering on answers (and as of yet no tagging mechanism, although I offered this as a solution to the problem) when a question gets too many answers (especially too many long winded answers) the question gets diminishing returns from new viewers.  If you consider the question your baby, I can see why this is good, but the question is everyone's baby.

Comment: I love finding a question with multiple, high-quality answers (usually partially overlapping in what they're saying). Really rich and interesting. Adds a lot of value to the site.